# iPad landscape mode only with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, ios6, ios-simulator, ipad

I am making an iPad app with landscape only mode supported, but when I add navigationController in my app, even though simulator by default is set on landscape mode, my app View is in portrait . This happens only when I try to add UINavigationController.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass UINavigationController and add these methods:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the supportet unterface orientations in your apps target summary:

[image]

Comment: Yes that's the first thing I had done. However, the issue still remained.

Comment: Ah. I see… Got another possible solution.